# Binding scss variables with an attached prop in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, sass

I can't seem to find what I'm looking for with this. I'm running into an issue where I wish to bind a prop to a custom `scss` variable.

I have the following "Card" `component`:

```
<template>
  <div class="option" v-bind:style="--optionBackground:url(img);" v-on:click="switchCards">
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="label">
      <div class="icon">
         <i class="fas fa-walking"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="info">
         <div class="main">Blonkisoaz</div>
         <div class="sub">Omuke trughte a otufta</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Card",
  props: {
    img: String
  },
  methods: {
    switchCards () {
       console.log('clicked')
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Ignore some of the placeholder scripts.

So, I'm trying to `v-bind:style="--optionBackground:url(img);"` where img is passed in as a prop from the parent `component` as follows:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="card) in cards" class="options" v-bind:key="card.id">
      <Card v-bind:img="card.img"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Card from "./components/Card.vue";

export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    Card
  },
  data () {
    return {
      cards: [
        { id: 1, img: 'https://66.media.tumblr.com/8b69cdde47aa952e4176b4200052abf4/tumblr_o51p7mFFF21qho82wo1_1280.jpg'},
        { id: 2, img: 'https://66.media.tumblr.com/f19901f50b79604839ca761cd6d74748/tumblr_o65rohhkQL1qho82wo1_1280.jpg'},
        { id: 3, img: 'https://66.media.tumblr.com/8b69cdde47aa952e4176b4200052abf4/tumblr_o51p7mFFF21qho82wo1_1280.jpg'},
        { id: 4, img: 'https://66.media.tumblr.com/5516a22e0cdacaa85311ec3f8fd1e9ef/tumblr_o45jwvdsL11qho82wo1_1280.jpg'}
      ]
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

However, I'm receiving the following error:

```
invalid expression: Unexpected token : in

  --optionBackground:url(img);

Raw expression: v-bind:style="--optionBackground:url(img);"
```

I've tried looking at as many use cases as possible, but I'm really not sure what to try next.

[image: invalid expression: Unexpected token : in]

Comment: `card) in cards` it's a typo? please remove the `)` and try again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple of things.

1. You can't bind a SASS (aka SCSS) variable to the component, as SASS variables are resolved at compile time rather than run time. You can, however, bind a CSS variable (aka custom property), which is what you appear to actually want based on the variable name.
2. The syntax for using CSS variables is a little different than you have shown. What I suspect you want is

   `<div class="option" v-bind:style="{'--optionBackground': backgroundImage}">`

and then define `backgroundImage` as a computed property.

```
computed: {
  backgroundImage() { return "url(" + this.img + ")"; }
}
```

(You can make the code more concise with template literals, but it looks like stack overflow doesn't handle those very well in answers.)

**Edited to add:** @boussadjira also correctly points out a typo in your code in the comments.